# How to get the responseText messages?

Tags: jquery

How do i get the various ajax messages for success, failures etc? i want to alert the success and error values to the user  . Here is my code  below

I think 200 is for success.. how do i access the  success and failure values so i can alert them and do something based on that

```
$(function () {
    $("#save").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.json",
            data: json_data,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function () {

                //if success forward to landing page else return to form for correctiion
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Which message are you talking about ?

Comment: Why not reading the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`

Comment: Also have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {  
                 $("#save").click(function() {  


                    $.ajax({  
                        type: "POST",  
                          url: "some.json",  
                          data: json_data,  
                          contentType : 'application/json',
                          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
                          // get success or failure from here
                        alert(jqXHR.responseText)
                          } 
                        }); 

                  });  
                });
```

more options for the jqXHR onject: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: what is the textStatus? where is that value textStatus coming from?

Comment: @user244394 jQuery internally calls ur success handler with the data, textStatus, jqXHR.. Please read the links which other people and I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Example: Send an id as data to the server, save some data to the server, and notify the user once it's complete. If the request fails, alert the user.

```
var menuId = $("ul.nav").first().attr("id");
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/